# onTurnError is not called from TeamsActivityHandler.onInvokeActivity

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

i'm implementing a bot for microsoft teams using `com.microsoft.bot:bot-integration-core` version 4.14
i'm subclassing `TeamsActivityHandler` and overriding methods like `onMessageActivity` and `onAdaptiveCardInvoke`
i also use `BotFrameworkAdapter` to add some middleware and `onTurnError` handler.
when i have an action, triggered from a button click for example, and this action raises an exception, then `onTurnError` is not called, since an error is handled in `TeamsActivityHandler` (https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-java/blob/main/libraries/bot-builder/src/main/java/com/microsoft/bot/builder/teams/TeamsActivityHandler.java#L181)
in case on an error in `onMessageActivity`, the `onTurnError` is called fine.
if i subclass from a parent of TeamsActivityHandler, which is `ActivityHandler` then i assume error handling will work fine.

so my question is:
how is onTurnError is supposed to be used in case of subclassing `TeamsActivityHandler` ?

Comment: I have tried the scenario in C#. Added `throw new ArgumentNullException()` in the method definition and I got the exception at onTurnError.  I have updated this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/50.teams-messaging-extensions-search) as your issue. It worked fine

Comment: Are you facing this issue while trying any sample? Can you share the link?